# perl POE::Component::Pool

Tags: perl, poe

The code below prints the result of the SQL query, but why won't it insert the record?

```
#!/cbilldata/media/perl/bin/perl
use Data::Dumper;
use POE;
use POE qw( Component::Pool::DBI );
my $user_name = "username";

POE::Session->create(
    inline_states => {
        _start => sub {
            my ($kernel, $heap) = @_[KERNEL, HEAP];

            my $dbpool = POE::Component::Pool::DBI->new(
                connections => 1,
                dsn         => "DBI:Oracle:192.168.90.225:1521/CRMDB",
                username    => "$user_name",
                password    => "password"
            );

            # Outstanding queries keep the calling session alive.

            $dbpool->query(
                callback => "handle_result",
                query    => "select price  from cost where rownum < 2 and price= ?",
                params   => ["0.03872515"],

                # userdata => "example"
            );

            $heap->{dbpool} = $dbpool;

        },

        handle_result => sub {
            my ($kernel, $heap, $results, $userdata) = @_[KERNEL, HEAP, ARG0, ARG1];

            # Will be an arrayref of hashrefs.

            for my $record (@{$results}) {
                print "$record->{PRICE} \n";
            }

            my $dbpool = $heap->{dbpool};

            # Queries which do not return data should use the do method.
            # If no callback is supplied, no callback happens.  This is
            # suitable for queries where the result is not necessarily
            # important.

            $dbpool->do(
                query => "INSERT INTO cost (cost_id,operation_id,price,description) VALUES (?,?,?,?)",
                args  => [10000685233, 1, 1, 'Western Samoa'],
            );

            # Ask for a clean shutdown.
            $dbpool->shutdown;
        },
    },
);

POE::Kernel->run();
```

Comment: You're using DBD::Oracle, I assume, so AUTOCOMMIT is usually set to on, by default.  Can you confirm the value of AUTOCOMMIT?  Not sure how you get an individual db handle with POE, but with a db handle from a DBI->connect() call, you could try printing out $dbh->{AutoCommit}